# Angular 2 router not working properly

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

The app was working fine with the old Angular 2 router, however when I switched to the"3.0.0-beta.2",the application doesn't load.
This is obviously just part of the application but I believe this is where the problem lies:

Files:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavComponent} from "./nav.component";
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<my-nav></my-nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    directives:[NavComponent,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class AppComponent{
}
```

app.routes.ts

```
import {AboutComponent} from "./about.component";
import {TasksComponent} from "./tasks.component";
import {WalleyComponent} from "./walley.component";
import {DashboardComponent} from "./dash-board.component";
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from "./404.component";
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'yourTasks', component: TasksComponent},
  {path: 'about',component: AboutComponent},
  {path: 'walley',component: WalleyComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
  ];
export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import  {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {TodoStore} from './todoStore.service';
import { appRouterProviders } from './app.routes';


bootstrap(AppComponent,[appRouterProviders,TodoStore]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

nav.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector:'my-nav',
    templateUrl: 'components/nav.component.html',
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class NavComponent{
    num: Number;
}
```

in nav.component.html I am using `[router-link] ="['/walley']"` to trigger navigation.

Any feedback on whether its the problem with the code or with the version of the router I am using will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[routerLink]` in your template html.  Make sure you use lowercase 'r', uppercase 'L' and no hyphens :)

Also, it's handy to bootstrap your router directives if you're going to be using routerLinks a lot in your application